# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "/html"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, gemfile

I'm following the Ruby on Rails tutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages and came across the following error

```
 StaticPages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
 Failure/Error: page.should have_content('Sample App')
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find xpath "/html"
 # (eval):2:in `text'
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7:in `(root)'
```

My Gem file is as follows

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.10'

gem 'jruby-openssl'

gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
group :development, :test do
   gem 'webrat'
   gem 'rspec-rails', ">= 2.10.0"
   gem 'capybara', ">= 1.1.2"
end
```

How do I get rid of this error and pass the rspec?
The source file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "StaticPages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      # puts page.html
      page.should have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382415/rails-3-2-capybara-capybaraelementnotfoundunable-to-find-xpath-html

Please check if this spec is in spec/controllers or spec/requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the problem is with webrat gem + capybara gem, try and remove webrat from your gemfile.

[check this issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/406)

Answer (score 4):

You may have an error that prevents the page from being rendered properly.

Use some debugging facilities for help :

- Inside your request spec, use `puts page.html` to print the page content during your spec.
- track the log files (log/test.log)

Could you show your ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb source ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that the problem is most likely with this line:

`visit '/static_pages/home'`

Run 'rake routes' to find out the path names and use one of them. For example, if you have a route named 'home', use:

visit home_path

If the path you want doesn't exist, add it to config/routes.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had same error but with different case.
I included `include Capybara::DSL` in `spec_helper.rb` (`rails_helper.rb`).

Then, when I run spec, silently a warning shows up `including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!`. but in some test I got `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "/html"`.

I had to include in `RSpec.configure` block.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my solution here, since I ran across this error, and the original question is maybe ambiguous about the actual cause of the Capybara error.

While completing the `def create` method in my controller, was testing for the submit button to re-direct back to the ("contextually relevant" controller) index page, though had *not* explicitly `redirect_to` the index within the `create` method.

Added `redirect_to "/<your_index_page_path_here>"` and got the test to pass/resolved the test failure in question.