# rails 3.2 capybara Capybara::ElementNotFound:Unable to find xpath "/html"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am trying to test my rails app with rspec 2.10.0 + capybara 1.1.2. Here is my test file

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe AdminPanelController do
      describe "index" do
        it "should have return code 200" do
          visit '/admin'
          page.should have_content "hello"
          #response.status.should be(200)
        end
      end
    end
```

And here are test result

```
 Failure/Error: page.should have_content "hello"
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find xpath "/html"
```

I google about this issue but find only information that webrat can be a problem however i do not have this gem installed. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 15):

Wrong type of test. This looks like a controller test, which does tests with methods like get and post and is in the spec/controllers folder. Request specs, which use capybara, reside in spec/requests. Run `$ rails generate scaffold SomeModel` to see how they each should look.

If you understood the above but would still like to use capybara for your controller test, modify your describe block:

```
describe AdminPanelController, :type => :request do
  ...
end
```

Comment: Searched high and low for this answer. Sharp one!

Comment: With Capybara 2.0, this should not be `type: :request` but rather `type: :feature`.