# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "/html" without webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I can't make Capybara to work in many of my integration tests.

When I visit certain pages, I get the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

And so when I try to use the `have_content()` selector, it raises the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: page.should have_content("HELLO")
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find xpath "/html"
```

Some of the pages of my apps I can visit just fine, but some other ones I can't. There are even some pages that work at some places, and not at others:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HomeController do

  it "shows the website description" do
    visit root_path
    puts page.html.length # ==> 108 (no html)
    ...
  end
end



require 'spec_helper'

describe FlowsController do

  it "should do stuff" do
    visit root_path
    puts page.html.length # ==> 4459, works even if the exact same one didn't work in home_controller_spec! 
    visit flows_path
    puts page.html.length # ==> 3402, works
    visit new_user_session_path
    puts page.html.length # ==> 3330, works
    within("form#new_user") do
      fill_in 'Email', :with => 'email@example.com'
      fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
      click_on 'Sign in'
    end
    puts page.html.length # ==> 108, No html
  end
end
```

I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606150/capybaraelementnotfound-unable-to-find-xpath-html) that this was an error that might occur when using Capybara and webrat at the same time. But I'm not using webrat at all, and I still get the error...

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'
gem 'devise'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# Add rspec for testing
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try passing an String to describe, instead of the Controller class

```
describe "whatever" do
  ...
end
```